# How to find the total number of occurance of text and files with find command

Tags: unix, find

I am trying to run `find` command to find out total number of occurrence of a particular text and also with another find command to get the number of files which has this text.

What I have right now is this command.

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i "abc"
```

This brings all the files which has the text abc etc. I want to get either one or two `find` command to get

1. Total number of times abc appears
2. Total number of files which has abc in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use more `grep(1)` options to do what you wish:

1. For the total number of times `abc` occurs, you need to take care of the case that `abc` is on a single line two or more times:

   ```
   find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -o -i abc | wc -l
   ```
2. For the total number of files that contain `abc`, you need to take care of the case that a single file contains `abc` two or more times:

   ```
   find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -i abc | wc -l
   ```

From the `grep(1)` manpage:

```
   -l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each
          input file from which output would normally have been
          printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.
          (-l is specified by POSIX.)
```

and

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching
          line, with each such part on a separate output line.
```

Comment: i totally forgot about the abcs on the same line. 

To shorten the script even more, use -c (count) flag in grep instead of piping to wc

Comment: @ReubenL., that would potentially output several counts if the input to `xargs(1)` are too long for a single execution of `grep(1)` -- yes, a little faster, and in many cases _much_ shorter and simpler :) but small piles of files tend to grow to large piles of files...

Comment: @sarnold,Thanks for your answer. I will try and get back to you

Comment: @sarnold, when i tried the first one, i got this error message.


$ find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -o -i abc | wc -l
find: bad option -print0
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
xargs: illegal option -- 0
xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]

Comment: That's unfortunate; the `-print0` option to `find(1)` and the `-0` option to `xargs(1)` provides for a significantly safer interpretation of filenames. However, if your platform does not have these options, and you are reasonably certain none of your filenames include a newline character, then you can use `-print` to `find(1)` and leave off the `-0` to `xargs(1)`. If a filename _does_ have an embedded newline, it'll potentially run the matching against unrelated files. (Annoying in this case case. If it were `rm -rf` or some other modification, it could have disastrous consequences.)